# DecodeURI with '+' instead of '%20'

Tags: javascript, decode

decodeURI('hello%20world') gives hello world
but
decodeURI('hello+world') gives hello+world

Is there a ways to decode data contain + instead of %20?

Comment: It gives `"hello world"`

Comment: @Rayon: Not in Chrome.

Comment: @FelixKling — I just tried this in chrome console :(

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? `decodeURI` knows nothing about plus signs.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to decode hello+world. I am using ajax to post some day and the data received is hello+world.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` sign is not considered a special character to decode by `decodeURI`. One approach is to convert all plus signs to `%20` before using `decodeURI`:

```
decodeURI(('h+w').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
```